# Why is my AND statement not working in MySQL/PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve tickets from a database that are created in the last 6 weeks. Therefore i am trying to use an delimiter which filters that period but the database time is based on an UNIX timestamp and i want to search on a logical date.

I've tried date(), timestamp(), CAST() in the last line of my query but most throw errors or don't actually filter the wanted results

```
SELECT  ticket,
    company,
    title,
    status,
    department,
    user,
    (FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp,"%d-%m-%Y")) AS 'Start date',
    (FROM_UNIXTIME(close_time,"%d-%m-%Y")) AS 'Close date'
FROM ticket_database
WHERE department IN ('stack_mysql')
**AND DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%d-%m-%Y') > '11-02-19'**
;
```

I expect that all tickets created on or after 11-02-19 are shown but instead it ignored this date and throws everything at me since 2006.

Help is appriciated

Comment: I think the problem is that `'11-02-19'` is being interpreted as a string, not a date. Maybe by using `STR_TO_DATE('11-02-19','%d-%m-%Y')` or something similar you manage to solve it

Comment: You tried `timestamp > '2019-02-11'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, based on this line:

```
(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp,"%d-%m-%Y")) AS 'Start date',
```

the `timestamp` column is a unix timestamp, not a date and thus can't be passed to `DATE_FORMAT`. Secondly, `11-02-19` is not a valid MySQL date format and thus can't be compared to a date directly; you need to use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert that to a date instead. So, to make it work, try this:

```
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) > STR_TO_DATE('11-02-19', '%d-%m-%y')
```

To allow MySQL to use an index on the `timestamp` column, remove the `FROM_UNIXTIME` call and convert the date into a timestamp instead:

```
AND timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('11-02-19', '%d-%m-%y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not the best idea to use a function on a field in the WHERE Clause. This will generate a FULL TABLE SCAN. MySQL must read each ROW, run the function and the compare.

Better is to use the function on the constant part of the compare, but here
is it is not nesecary

```
SELECT  ticket,
    company,
    title,
    status,
    department,
    user,
    (FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`,"%d-%m-%Y")) AS 'Start date',
    (FROM_UNIXTIME(close_time,"%d-%m-%Y")) AS 'Close date'
FROM ticket_database
WHERE department IN ('stack_mysql')
AND `timestamp` > unix_timestamp('2019-02-11 00:00:00');
```

Note: Make your life easier. Dont use reserved Keywords like timestamp not as fieldnames. if you do that you must quote it in backticks

Comment: @Nick2 - i have change it in my answer